# Eliminar signos y simbolos de una cadena en python

Tags: python

si por ejemplo tengo la siguiente cadena de caracteres:

```
DimcusTomer V
Customer|D INT
FirstName VARCHAR(45)
LastName VARCHAR(45)
ZipC0de VARCHAR(45)
City VARCHAR(45)

State VARCHAR(45)

'| |_| I’
```

como puedo hacer para eliminar todos los caracteres que no sean letras y/o numero a excepcion de las parentesis del mismo modo como puedo eliminar las lineas en blanco?

Answer (score 0):

Presuponiendo que tienes los datos en una lista almacenados, podrías hacer esto:

```
import re

#Creamos la lista
lista = ['DimcusTomer V',

'Customer|D INT',

'FirstName VARCHAR(45)',

'LastName VARCHAR(45)',

'ZipC0de VARCHAR(45)',

'City VARCHAR(45)',

'     ',

'State VARCHAR(45)',


'     ',

'| |_| I’']


'''Lo que hay dentro de re.sub le decimos que elimine todo lo que no sean letras,
digitos espacios y parentesis'''
lista_sin_caracteres = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\s()]', '', string).strip() for string in lista]

# Solo cogemos los strings si existe algo dentro
lista_limpiada= [string for string in lista_sin_caracteres if string]

#La lista quedaría así
print(lista_limpiada)

['DimcusTomer V',
 'CustomerD INT',
 'FirstName VARCHAR(45)',
 'LastName VARCHAR(45)',
 'ZipC0de VARCHAR(45)',
 'City VARCHAR(45)',
 'State VARCHAR(45)',
 'I']
```

Comment: Y porque no usar ```.split()```?